# Gradle Plugin Publishing Plugin with android

Tags: java, android, maven, plugins, gradle

I am developing a custom gradle plugin based on a Android project. And I want to publish my plugin via another plugin (https://plugins.gradle.org/docs/publish-plugin) This is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: "com.gradle.plugin-publish"

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath "com.gradle.publish:plugin-publish-plugin:0.9.3"
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

group = 'com.myplugin'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: uri('../repo'))
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile gradleApi()
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}

pluginBundle {
    website = 'http://www.example.com/'
    description = 'Welcome to bla bla'
    tags = ['test', 'test']
    plugins {
        PluginName {
            id = 'com.something'
            displayName = 'My Plugin'
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this:

```
./gradlew uploadArchives
```

I get this error:

```
Parallel execution with configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'mylib'.
> The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.543 secs
```

Comment: Clearly the plugin-publish plugin is adding the java plugin, which the android plugin you've added doesn't like. I would think they're incompatible. I'm curious though - why does your plugin project have the android plugin if you're not going to build an android lib/app ?

Comment: I am actually creating a android lib

Comment: Well is it an android lib or a gradle plugin? A gradle plugin would be packaged as a jar, I imagine an android lib would be aar? How about you create a separate project for the plugin, that depends on your android lib, but is just a java (or groovy) project?

Comment: I am sorry. It is a gradle plugin that depends of android plugin. It means that in my code I use android classes. I don't want to create a jar.

Comment: Because I use android classes inside my gradle plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry, what I really wanted to do is described here:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-and-publishing-an-android-library--cms-24582

Publish my android library so anyone could access it via gradle

Comment: In which case, what you really need is the `maven-publish` plugin, not the `plugin-publish`. Also depending on which repo you're uploading to, you might want the artifactory or bintray plugin

Comment: The `plugin-publish` plugin is for creating plugins like the `android` plugin